# How do I set a password for an existing account?

Tags: password, chromebook

I'm very new to Linux, as I just got a Chromebook as a gift this evening and would like to change it to Linux. I went ahead and downloaded crouton and set it up through the terminal; but when it came time to set a password, I couldn't type. I had heard that it wasn't echoing due to security measures, so I entered my password anyways, but the terminal kept telling me;

Sorry, passwords do not match
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged

I kept trying to type a password (while it kept giving me the same message) until I got to this point;
Password left unset. To set a password, inside the chroot run: passwd ivor
Now, I'm not sure what to do, because I have 0 experience with Linux, so if someone could assist me in setting a new password I would very much appreciate it.